# Phonetic filter factory for Hindi

Tags: solr, lucene, search-engine, data-analysis

I am working with Apache solr ,I am trying to use phonetic filter factory , I have tried all the encoders that are available with solr.PhoneticFilterFactory but none of them is supporting indian languages . Is there any other Filter/Method available so that i can get phonetic representation for indian languages e.g Hindi,tamil,Bengali etc

If not then how we can modify existing filters to support these languages.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the new Beider Morse Filter Factory, which was just added in version 3.6 and is (alas) not yet well-documented?

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.BeiderMorseFilterFactory

It was developed for phonetic searching of Central and Eastern European surnames, but maybe it would work for other languages too.  I have personally found that it works much better than Soundex or the other older soundalike methods.

Comment: i have tried this filterFactory it seems that it do not support hindi.

Comment: Tried this filter. It does not work for hindi names.