# Is there a "SOUNDS LIKE" function in CQL like the one in MySQL?

Tags: cassandra, cql

When I used MySQL I was able to query the database with a statement like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE col LIKE "%attribute%";`

Is there a way I can do that in Cassandra?

Answer (score 3):

Cassandra CQL doesn't have a `LIKE` operator.  It has limited filtering capabilities so you are restricted to equals, range queries on some numeric fields, and the IN operator which is similar to equals.

The most common approach to doing searches of Cassandra data seems to be pairing Cassandra with Apache Solr.  Or you can pair it with Apache Spark which has more filtering capabilities than CQL.

Comment: You may also find these posts interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13023424/phonetic-filter-factory-for-hindi & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22552446/solr-search-using-contains-sound-like

Comment: check out DSE Search http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.7/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchIntro.html

Answer (score 1):

If your col is a collection of data like set, list, map. You could use CONTAINS, to perform search.

Sample:

> SELECT id, description FROM products WHERE features CONTAINS '32-inch';

For map data type,

> SELECT id, description FROM products WHERE features CONTAINS KEY 'refresh-rate';

References:
http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql-in-2-1

Comment: (lastname  | firstname
-----------+-----------
       Doe |      John
   Farther |     Jacob
      Huey |     Roger
   Anzaldo |    Daniel
   Penrose |    Guyman
    Sigman |      Matt
  McCarthy |       Bob) --this is my table. How do I select * from the table where the first name contains "man". It's coming back with an operator error. QUERY: cqlsh:demo> select firstname, lastname from demo where firstname contains 'man';
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="No secondary indexes on the restricted columns support the provided operators: "

Comment: Just 2 questions, to help you better,
1) Is "firstname" column a collection of data like Set, List or Map?
Example: firstname = {name1, name2, name3}
2) If your firstname is a collection, Then Did you define "firstname" as Secondary or primary index?

Comment: lastname is primary key, firstname is just text.

Comment: contains can only be used for collection data type, which holds list of data

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. I was wondering why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

CQL LIKE statements now available are in Scylla Open Source 3.2 RC1, the release candidate for Scylla, a CQL-compatible database. We'd love feedback before release. Here's the details:

- CQL: LIKE Operation #[4477](https://github.com/scylladb/scylla/issues/4477)

The new CQL LIKE keyword allows matching any column to a search pattern, using % as a wildcard. Note that LIKE only works with ALLOW FILTERING.

LIKE Syntax support:

'_' matches any single character

'%' matches any substring (including an empty string)

'\' escapes the next pattern character, so it matches verbatim

any other pattern character matches itself

an empty pattern matches empty text fields

For example:

> INSERT INTO t (id, name) VALUES (17, ‘Mircevski’)
>
> SELECT * FROM t where name LIKE 'Mirc%' allow filtering

Source: [[RELEASE] Scylla 3.2 RC1](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scylladb-users/BO6kBFclCKc/2Gg8KuAsAAAJ) [2](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scylladb-users/BO6kBFclCKc/2Gg8KuAsAAAJ)